# A Tool/Program To Run Google Search with Regexes and Basic Scripting

Tags: script, google-search

I just saw the movie The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo and there is a scene where a person searches google search in a command-line using basic scripting something akin to bash. What tool can possibly achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://boolify.org doesn't do exactly this, but I still find it to be very useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/459379/a-tool-program-to-run-google-search-with-regexes-and-basic-scripting

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done - Google read's the parameters (the search query) as a string only - it can't read and execute a script; this would potentially be a security issue.

The only way you could do this I guess would be to use the regex to create the string or, upon each regex pattern, query Google, scan the results and then continue or re-scan etc! This could result in too much traffic to Google and I would *assume* they'll ban your IP (or grey list or similar).